# Замена WebClient в .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net

Я использую WebClient для авторизации при помощи куки на веб-сервисе.

```
class CookieWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }


    public CookieWebClient()
    {
        this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }


    public CookieWebClient(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null) return base.GetWebRequest(address);            
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Чем можно заменить этот код, чтобы можно было принять куки и продолжать работать с веб-сервисом, авторизовавшись?

Comment: А что с этим кодом не так?

Comment: В Compact Framework мне не удалось найти поддержку WebClient.

Comment: А, там просто нету WebClient? Понятно.

Comment: Вроде бы [советуют](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25694191/276994) использовать `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: @VladD, не советуют. Просто никто не ответил, и поэтому автор вопроса сделал ещё один "велосипед", да разместил его в качестве принятого ответа для своего-же вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по предыдущему вопросу - у вас есть полный контроль над серверным кодом. И сейчас вы занимаетесь изобретением велосипедов.

Незачем вам там использовать Web Api. RESTfull-сервисы хороши только когда у вас есть некий готовый функционал, и вы хотите по-быстрому сделать его доступным для некого JavaScript-кода выполняющегося в веб-браузере. Для бизнес-приложений он не подходит, и применяться там не будет никогда. Такова его специфика.

Для CF всегда лучше всегда использовать WCF-сервисы(SOAP), вместо Web Api. Там авторизация из коробки, все вызовы строго типизированы, внятная обработка исключений. Ну и просто приятней когда можно нажать в студии правой кнопкой на проекте, выбрать "Add Web Service", вбить url конечной точки, а всё остальное студия сделает за вас. Вопрос об отсутствующем WebClient отпадет сам по себе.

Comment: Посмотрю в сторону WCF. Спасибо.